# MAPE vs R-squared in regression models

Tags: forecasting, prediction, r-squared, model-evaluation, mape

Usually regression models are evaluated using $R^2$. I understand this metric can be misleading too at times but as far as I understand the first parameter we look at is $R^2$.

There is another parameter which is often used and it is $MAPE$. 
Both are functions of errors between predicted and true value. I am just wondering if there are certain cases where one should be preferred above another?

$R^2$ can become negative if being used on test data (on which the model is not built). Is this a reason to not use $R^2$ in these cases?

Can anyone give a qualitative insight on where $MAPE$ should be used and where $R^2$ should be used.

Comment: Have your read the [Wikipedia article on MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error)'s list of disadvantages with the metric?

Comment: @Alexis yes I have. I did not see any comparison with R^2 and more interested in comparing these two metrics. Does R^2 overcome any of the disadvantages which MAPE has?

Comment: Yes. For example, $R^{2}$ is, for a model with a single predictor, bounded by 0 and 1. Adjusted-$R^{2}$, which is a quantity one gets with more than one predictor variable breaks some of the interpretability of $R^{2}$. However, there are other measures, such as [*generalized* $R^{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Generalized_R2), which provides much of the interpretability, even for multiple predictors, and even for things like binomial-outcome link regressions (which don't have residuals in the same way as OLS regression).

Comment: Very much related: [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at [the definition of $R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination): if $y_i$ are the actuals and $f_i$ the predictions, then we let $\overline{y}$ denote the mean of the actuals and $e_i = y_i-f_i$ the error. Then

$$ R^2 := 1-\frac{\sum e_i^2}{\sum (y_i-\overline{y})^2}. $$

If we want to maximize $R^2$, we note that we cannot influence the denominator in this formula. Thus, *maximizing $R^2$ is equivalent to minimizing the sum of squared errors* (or the Mean Squared Error, [mse](/questions/tagged/mse)).

And this actually makes a lot of sense. The prediction that minimizes the expected MSE is the expected value of each $Y_i$ (the distribution from which we observe $y_i$). This is often what we want. Note that other error measures like the [MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299713/1352) may be minimized by other quantities, so minimizing the MAPE may yield biased point predictions.

For the difference between the MAPE and $R^2$ (also known as MSE, as we have seen), see this earlier post: [The difference between MSE and MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11636/1352).