# Accuracy metric for comparing Time Series models?

Tags: time-series, arima, accuracy, model-comparison

I'm writing a blog post on forecasting time series with autoregression. In it, I compare the performance of SLR, ARIMA, and SARIMAX on forecasting the number of Home Sales in Seattle (see below).

All 3 have different numbers of "input parameters": SLR just uses time, ARIMA and SARIMAX both use time and 12 lagged $y$ values. **I say "input parameters" b/c I'm not sure how to consider $y$.*

I'm currently using RMSE to compare them. Is this an acceptable practice, or is there another measure I should use that takes model complexity into account (e.g. something akin to adjusted R^2)?

I know that MAPE is a commonly used forecasting metric. But like RMSE, I'm not sure it's appropriate for comparing models with different numbers of input parameters. Just wondering if there's anything better out there.

[image]

Comment: Are you measuring RMSE in-sample or out-of-sample?

Comment: Out of sample. I'm interested in the RMSE of the forecast, plus the RMSE of the in-sample ARIMA and SARIMAX models are nearly identical (the differences b/t them only really show out-of-sample).

Comment: Rather than choosing a single measure, it is more common to include several relevant measures of accuracy for prediction.

Comment: These kinds of adjustments for model complexity are typical of in-sample measures, but not of out-of-sample measures, which tackle overfitting in an entirely different way. You can compare RMSE/MAPE/MASE/etc out-of-sample between these models, just make sure that your exogenous regressors aren't assumed known in the future if they aren't really.

Comment: @ChrisHaug: do you want to post your comment as an answer? In addition, [the forecasting textbooks listed at this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352) all give error metrics commonly used in forecast evaluation. OP may be interested in [the shortcomings of the MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352). And [$R^2$ is not commonly used in forecast evaluation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/327464/1352).