# Changing OOB scoring metric for RandomForestRegressor from r2 to MSE

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn

In sklearn's documentation https://scikit-learn.org/1.4/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html it states that the default scoring for OOB samples are r2. It also states that you can provide your own metric by "providing a callable with signature metric(y_true, y_pred) to use a custom metric."

However, I am not entirely sure how I would implement this. I would like to use MSE instead of r2. Can anybody help? There does not seem to be any previous examples I can find where they have managed to implement their own scoring.

**Further:** Why is that sklearn always using r2 as the scoring metric? I have never heard of using this before. I always thought that the go-to was MSE or RMSE, so why does sklearn always use r2 scoring?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Questions about software implementations are considered off-topic here. However, there is a real statistical question lurking beneath that about using (R)MSE vs $R^2$. Could you please edit to emphasize the statistics content over the software? $//$ [I have some thoughts on `r2_score`.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score)

Comment: Depending on what convention you use for "out of sample $R^2$" per @Dave's link, [maximizing $R^2$ may be equivalent to minimizing MSE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/327482/1352).